# What does a C# for loop do when all the expressions are missing. eg for(;;) {}

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, for-loop

I can only assume it's an infinite loop.

Can I leave out any of the three expressions in a for loop? Is there a default for each when omitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed an infinite loop.

Under the hood the compiler/jitter will optimize this to (effectively) a simple JMP operation.

It's also effectively the same as:

```
while (true)
{
}
```

(except that this is also optimized away, since the (true) part of a while expression usually requires some sort of comparison, however in this case, there's nothing to compare.  Just keep on looping!)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it's an infinite loop.

Examples:

`for (; ;) { }` (aka: The Crab)

`while (true) { }`

`do { } while (true)`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's an infinite loop. You can leave out any of the three expressions, though in my experience it's typically either the first or all 3.

Answer (score 3):

It's an infinitely loop. Effectively, its the same as this:

```
while (true)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`for (; ;) { }` is infinite loop, you are correct.

if you want to use it, then you have to put some condition in your loop body, so that it can exit out from loop.

```
for (; ;) 
{
    if (conditionTrue)
        break;
    else
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no defaults.  Nothing is initialised, nothing is incremented and there's no test for completion.

Answer (score 2):

There are no defaults for first and third part (they default to nothing and it would work). The default for conditional expression is `true` which will make `for(;;)` effectively an infinite loop. (If the default was supposed to be `false`, it would have been useless to have such a construct).

Answer (score 1):

Just like in C and C++ you can omit any of the three, or all three.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's C# Programmer's Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte(VS.71).aspx) says:

> All of the expressions of the for statement are optional; for example, the following statement is used to write an infinite loop:

```
for (;;) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an infinite loop :).