# Use of "for (;;)" in a C# application?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I've been looking through some sample source code for an application I use and I came across this line:

```
for (;;)
{
// The rest of the application's code
}
```

It looks like this is to create an infinite loop, but I'm not familiar with ";;" and it's very hard to Google unfortunately.

Comment: definite duplicate of [What does a C# for loop do when all the expressions are missing. eg for(;;) {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697307/what-does-a-c-for-loop-do-when-all-the-expressions-are-missing-eg-for)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# for loop syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245043/c-sharp-for-loop-syntax)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, that is an infinite loop. It's an ordinary for loop with no condition expression.

From the [documentation for `for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx):

> All of the expressions of the for statement are optional; for example, the following statement is used to write an infinite loop:
>
> ```
> for (; ; )
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, is it common practice (IE: Not a hack?)

Comment: One thing to note is  that you should have a condition on which to break from it, to have a non-ending loop is usually bad...
@toleero, it is a matter of style. I like to use the `while (true) {}` loop instead, it is more straight to the point IMO, but either one is standard practice.

Comment: @t84 - Fairly common, though many use `while(true){}` for readability.

Comment: @toleero: It's not a hack, but it has a slight smell to it... You should try to put the condition in the loop statement if practically possible, instead of breaking out of the loop.

Comment: @toleero - I don't know about C#, but in C and C++, that is the cannocical way to do an infinite loop.

Answer (score 9):

it is infinite loop.

equal to

```
while (true) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just want to clarify :

`;;` is not a special operator or something - it's a regular for loop.

regular for loop looks like that:

`for (do_before_loop**;** finish_loop_when_this_condition_is_false**;** do_after_each_iteration);`

if you leave all 3 parts empty you get `;;` - and since you don't have an exit condition - this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Normally You write Your loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
// The rest of the application's code
}
```

Now, when You want Your loop to be infinite one, You just have to remove the "int i = 0", condition "i < 10", and incrementation "i++". If You do this, then in a for statement You will see only ";;"

```
for (;;)
{
// The rest of the application's code
}
```

Comment: Technically, for the loop to be infinite, all you have to remove is the condition (i<10).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's an infinite loop.

All parameters in the `for` statement are optional, and the condition defaults to `true`, so it's the same as:

```
for (;true;)
```

or:

```
while (true)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as `for (<initial>; <condition>; <increment>)`, you're simply leaving out initial, condition and increment. In this case, condition will always be considered true.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting reading in this article:

http://csharpdevelop.blogspot.com/2004/05/writing-infinite-loop.html

> This kind of code occurs quite a bit
>   in worker threads waiting for some
>   work to do. It is a common code
>   pattern. All code in the looping
>   statements body is critical. The "quit
>   condition" must be checked frequently.
>   This implies that the work to do must
>   be short. Usually this is one smaller
>   chuck of work out of the larger set of
>   work it was given to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Its the first entry in google if you are interested I googled
C# for ;;
And got this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx
Click C# and msdn states:

All of the expressions of the for statement are optional; for example, the following statement is used to write an infinite loop:

for (; ; )
{
    // ...
}

Answer (score 0):

A normal for loop has these elements

```
 for ( for-initializer ; for-condition ; for-iterator ) embedded-statement
```

e.g.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
   foo();
}
```

Any of those elements can be omitted, and you're left with `for(;;)` , which is an infinite loop.

The c# language [specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) specifically states

> If the for-condition is omitted from
>   the for statement, then evaluation of
>   definite assignment proceeds as if
>   for-condition were replaced with true
>   in the above expansion.

So, `for(;;)` is the same as `for(;true;)`

Answer (score 0):

It is an ordinary use of the infinite loop.
We use this loop in case we don't know how many times we need to execute the code inside the loop. Therefore we need to define also a condition to get out of this loop.
Here is an example of receiving a long message from a server :

```
for (;;)
{
     //Receive the maximum allowed size of the message
     //Save(Concatenate) the received data in a variable (TotalReceivedData)
     // If the length of the received part of the message is equal to zero , break the operation
     //<Break the loop>if(message.length == 0){break;}</Break the loop> 
}
```

And here you can use your full received message stored in the variable TotalReceivedData.

I added this example because I just came across a case like this.