# wait() does not wait for every child

Tags: c, parent-child, wait, exit-code, waitpid

I have a loop that creates 'n' child processes. The processes go into a separate program and sleep for 'x' seconds then return with exit status 'x'. The issue is when I try to wait for each individual process. It seems that my wait() call wait for the last made process and then the program exits. I would like it so that which ever child exits I can print their information and then wait for the next child to exit and print their information...and so on.

code:

```
int main()
{
      char input[12];
      int n, i, ch;
      pid_t pid;
      int status={0};

      printf("Enter an integer: ");
      fgets(input, 12, stdin);
      if (input[10] == '\n' && input[11] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }
      rmnewline(input);

      n = atoi(input);

      for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
      {
      pid = fork();
      if(pid == 0)
        execl("/home/andrew/USP_ASG2/sleep", "sleep", NULL);
      }

      for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
      {
        wait(&status);
        if(WIFEXITED(status))
        {
          int exitstat = WEXITSTATUS(status);
          printf("Child %d is dead with exit status %d\n", pid, exitstat);
        }
      }
}
```

output:

```
In child 15930
In child 15929
In child 15928
Child 15930 is dead with exit status 5
Child 15930 is dead with exit status 5
Child 15930 is dead with exit status 5
```

Comment: Aside: as a matter of style, `i<=n-1` would be clearer as `i<n`

Comment: @WeatherVane  No. With array offsets being zero-based, `for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )` is the canonical way to write a `for` loop in C.  Just Google "c for loop".  See many examples:  http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-for-loop-while-loop-break-and-continue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604500/use-of-for-in-a-c-sharp-application http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/12/c-loops-examples/  Also, leaving out the subtraction can result in slightly improved performance, especially on a register-starved architecture like x86.

Comment: @AndrewHenle are you sure you read my comment corerctly? What if `n==0`, the loop control `i<=n-1` could go mad when unsigned. I wrote "clearer as", not "clearer than".

Comment: @WeatherVane I do seem to have misread your comment.  I should have recognized that.  Yes it would be clearer as `i < n`.  Well, we're in agreement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to capture the return value of `wait()`, so `pid` still contains the pid of the last process you forked off.

Do this:

```
pid = wait(&status);
```

And you'll get the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! Though all the children still exit at the same time with the same "random" exit status. EDIT: I'm currently changing how the seed of the random number is generated, as that may be the problem.

Comment: @AndrewRicci  When you `fork()`, the child process runs independently of the parent and of any other child process.  They are all scheduled separately by the OS, so you can't control when each one ends without using pipes, signals, or shared memory mutexed.  The exit value is dependent entirely on the child process.

Comment: The program they exec  to generates a random number with 'srand(time(NULL));' then itsleep for a random time between 0 and 9. Its not control its just they all should be exiting at different times.

Comment: @AndrewRicci The `time()` function returns the current time in seconds since the epoch.  Since your loop does all of the forks in quick succession, it's highly likely the child processes start during the same second.  That means they would use the same seed and therefore would all generate the same random number and sleep for the same amount of time.

Comment: Changed the seed(to srand(getpid())). Shitty seed, but it does in fact change the times of exit. Thank you dbush!