# C# for loop syntax

Tags: c#

I'm working on some C# code that has loop syntax that I've never seen before:

```
for (;;)
{
  //Do some stuff
}
```

What does a for loop without a `init;` `condition;` or `increment` do?  By the way it's really hard to find meaningful search results on the internet for `"for (;;) c#`" on any search engine I tried.

-Eric

Comment: `If null is null then keep going. At the end , null + null` is how I've always read. It's an infinite loop, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: So it goes unless there's a break, throw, or something?

Comment: @Eric, correct.

Comment: @Symon your comment is actually an answer. Please post it as an answer so we can upvote it :)

Comment: Would this be valid syntax in C, Java, JavaScript, etc?

Comment: this is a while(true) loop, very bad code style. you need to break or throw and exception to get out of the loop.

Comment: The empty condition statement is the real key here. Without a condition, the loop will run forever unless something inside the block terminates it. I believe it's generally considered more intentional to write `while(true)` because that explicitly states the infinite-loop condition (and `while` conditions are not optional).

Comment: It was semi-idiomatic in the early days of C.  (I can remember a "cute" macro someone wrote that looked like `#define EVER ;;` that allowed you to write `for(EVER) { /* code */ }`).  I remember seeing it a lot in 80's era C code, not so much in early 90s C and C++ code and very rarely in the last decade or two. *Yeah, I'm that old, but I'm guessing the person who wrote the code you are looking at is old as well*

Comment: He's younger than me ;^)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of "for (;;)" in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604500/use-of-for-in-a-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 12):

That is an `infinite loop`. Like you stated, it will run until a part of it breaks (throws an exception or otherwise exists the loop) or the machine runs out of resources to support the loop.

```
for (;;)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Is just the same as:

```
do
{
   //do stuff
}while (true)
```

---

```
while(true)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: There is no variable to set to `null`. Refer to [the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-for-statement): Parts 1 and 3 ("for_initializer" and "for_iterator") are empty statements and do nothing. Part 2 ("for_condition") is a special case, where the lack of a statement is specified to be treated as if the condition evaluated `true`.

Comment: @Symon To be clear, in the context I linked, the `?` indicates an optional symbol in the ANTLR grammar C# compilers use to parse C# source code. There are no C# variables here.

Comment: @JoeSewell, ahh. That makes more sense. That must be where my confusion of it must've been.

Comment: @RufusL , I see. Read more of the documentation on it and I understand where I was wrong. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks for fixing the answer +1

Answer (score 9):

The syntax of a `for` loop is thus:

```
for (condition; test; action)
```

Any one of those items can be omitted (per the language spec). So what you've got is an infinite loop. A similar approach:

```
while (true) { // do some stuff }
```

Comment: For reference, [the C# draft specification on the `for` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-for-statement). Notice the "If the for_condition **is not present** or if the evaluation yields true, control is transferred to the embedded statement." (emphasis mine).

Comment: Calling the first argument `condition` is confusing, and the third one `action` is vague; the terms from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for#structure-of-the-for-statement) -  `for (initializer; condition; iterator)` - tell a better story.

Comment: @mklement0 I don't remember why I put "condition" there, so I agree with you on that, but the reason why I put "action" is because you can do other things besides increment a variable.

Comment: While it's _possible_ to do other things in the `iterator` section, its _primary purpose_ is to iterate, so I think it's better to call it `iterator` - while perhaps adding a _note_ that points out that you're technically not restricted to incrementing a loop variable.

Comment: Where in your link does it say that that is its primary purpose?

Comment: (You need to @-mention me to be notified of follow-up comments). It's implied by the _name_ of the section and it is certainly the typical use case. Generally, if constructs have official names, it's always best to use them (and link to their definition) to avoid confusion.

Comment: @mklement0 And it's always best to name things as an indicator of what they represent. Hence, this is why I chose to call it "action" instead of "iterator." The simple fact here is that, regardless of the typical-ness of the use case, the _documented_ behavior of the third part of the `for` is that it can be an expression--it can even be multiple expressions.

Comment: It's best to name things for their _gist_ - it's impossible to pack a full story into a single name. As suggested, you can always add a _note_ to explain that and how the name doesn't tell the _full_ story. Additionally, deviating from the official terminology warrants a note too.

Answer (score 8):

`for (;;)`

**Short answer**: It is an infinite loop which is equivalent to `while(true)`

**Long answer**:  `for (initializer; condition; iterator)` [Structure of the `for` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for#structure-of-the-for-statement)

- initializer block: Do not initialize variable.
- condition block: with no condition (means execute infinitely) => while true
- iterator block: with no operation to any variable (no iterator)

[for(;;) example from official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for#examples)

Answer (score 4):

This type of for loop is an infinite loop. It is the equivalent of `while(true){stuff to be executed...}`. It keeps on going until it hits a break, return, or a goto to a label outside the loop.

A for loop has three parts, an initialization, a condition, and a block to be executed after the loop. Without a condition to be tested against, the loop will just keep on going.